# Should Document library versioning be enabled when storing XML files?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, versioning, xml

Should Document library versioning be enabled when storing XML files? I know the advantages of turning it on for MS office documents. Does it do any good turning it on for XML files and folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the benefits of versioning in SharePoint whether you are adding versioning on word documents or on XML files.

**When to enable**:

So whenever your file contents or its metadata going to be changed and you want to see the changes made or restore the previous version then you should enable versioning.

**Benefits**:

1. Ability to audit the history of an item:
   Version history allows you to retrace the history of an item or a document, since the date and time it was first created till present.
2. Ability to track metadata changes:
   Any metadata changes are perfectly visible in the version history log.
3. Ability to track content changes:
   If you enable versioning on a document library, you can access any previous versions of the document just by clicking on a previous version link.
4. Ability to restore previous versions:
   You can also restore older versions if need be.
5. Ability to compare SharePoint versions:
   This is not necessarily a SharePoint feature, but more of a Word feature. Essentially what you can do is compare different SharePoint versions of the document in Word using MS Word Compare feature.

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of versioning are the same no matter what type of file it is.  You should use versioning when:

- The contents of the document are going to change, and
- You want to be able to have access to previous versions of the document, for whatever reason (to see what changed, restore to a previous version if the current version is no longer valid, etc.)